# Mathematic correct plotting rational function

Tags: limits

What is range of $$-\frac{1-4\epsilon+3\epsilon^2}{1-\epsilon^2}$$

assuming $\epsilon\in(0,1)$?

It looks like $$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow1}-\frac{1-4\epsilon+3\epsilon^2}{1-\epsilon^2}=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow1}-\frac{-4+6\epsilon}{-2\epsilon}=1$$

However plotting on mathematica $-\frac{1-4\epsilon+3\epsilon^2}{1-\epsilon^2}$ explodes to infinity as $\epsilon\rightarrow1$.

Is $2$ an upper bound for $$1-\frac{1-4\epsilon+3\epsilon^2}{1-\epsilon^2}$$ with $\epsilon\in(0,1)$?

Comment: It doesn't "explode" when I plot it

Comment: Can you paste your mathematica results? May be I am mistaking.

Comment: I used wolfram: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x+to+1+of+-%281-4x%2B3x%5E2%29%2F%281-x%5E2%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Note that

$$1-\frac{1-4\epsilon+3\epsilon^2}{1-\epsilon^2}=\frac{1-\epsilon^2}{1-\epsilon^2}-\frac{1-4\epsilon+3\epsilon^2}{1-\epsilon^2}=\frac{4\epsilon-4\epsilon^2}{1-\epsilon^2}=4\frac{\epsilon(1-\epsilon)}{(1-\epsilon)(1+\epsilon)}=4\frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}=\frac{4}{\frac 1 \epsilon+1}$$

So for $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ this value is in $(0,2)$

EDIT: $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 1} \frac{4}{\frac 1 \epsilon+1} = \frac 4 2 $$ Note that between the third and the fourth equals sign, I removed a removable singularity. Basically on the left and on the right side of $\epsilon = 1$ you the curve will converge to the same value $2$ so we can remove this singularity as you can see in this step.

Comment: So do you trust Mathematica? Just note that I used the expression you have down there, the one before your edit.

Comment: I am confused. That has been my conviction that mathematica is flawless. Is what you did legal? To one who has not seen limits in a decade, this is amazing I think.

Comment: So where did I go wrong?

Comment: No I do not think that Mathematica has problems solving this, but first, did you enter your equation correctly? Second: Did you try to understand what I wrote there / did you find errors? I am not claiming my calculations are flawless=)

Comment: if you use $\epsilon=0.99999$, can you tell me what happens directy and with your calculation?

Comment: @Turbo Mathematica is not flawless, but it certainly handles these things without error. You probably didn't enter the expression correctly. See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%281-4x%2B3x%5E2%29%2F%281-x%5E2%29 There's no explosion near $1$.

Comment: @Turbo I just added a comment in the original answer, I hope that helps. Did you try to understand what I did there?

Comment: That helped very much clear. I cant believe, my calculus skills have gone rusty and I could not figure this explanation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem in Mathematica!

If you define
$$T=1-\frac{1-4\epsilon+3\epsilon^2}{1-\epsilon^2},$$

And use the following command:

```
T//Simplify,
```

the output generated is

$$\frac{4\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}$$

Mathematica will, in general, not automatically simplify your expression.

Comment: Makes sense with this explanation.

Comment: So issue I found is genuine?

Comment: Try this:

F[x_] := 1 - (1 - 4 x + x^2)/(1 - x^2); // Simplify

Plot[F[x], {x, 0, 1}]